# mouseListener not working

Tags: java, mouselistener

I'm coding a simple game but I can't get my mouseListener to work. My keyListener is working fine but not the mouseListner.
Here is some code:

```
    public Game(String title, int width, int height){
    this.falling = true;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.title = title;
    keyManager = new KeyManager();
    mouseInput = new MouseInput();        
}

private void init(){      
    display = new Display(title, width, height);
    display.getFrame().addKeyListener(keyManager);
    display.getFrame().addMouseListener(mouseInput);
    display.getFrame().addMouseMotionListener(mouseInput);
}
```

In the mouseInput class:

```
public class MouseInput extends MouseAdapter{

private int x;
private int y;

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}}
```

Comment: When you say it doesnt work, is it behaving like its not registering your mouseEvents, or is it not compiling?

Comment: Not registering my mouseEvents

Comment: how long is the program? If it's not too long, perhaps you could post up the entire code for us to help you debug :)

Comment: It's 7 classes but I can post the main game class

Comment: that would help

Comment: I cant seem to post the whole thing, I'll keep trying

Answer (score 0):

```
package infiniterunner;

import infiniterunner.gfx.ImageLoader;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font; 
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Game implements Runnable{
private Display display;
public int width, height;
public String title;

private boolean running;
private Thread thread;

public BufferStrategy bs;
public Graphics g;
Font header = new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 50);
Font button = new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 40);

private final int margin=200;
private final int dyPlate=1;

private int velY=1;
private int dxBall=6;
private int wentBy=0;
private int xMargin;
private int gameOverY=250;
private int background=1;

private float alpha1 = 0.0f;
private float alpha2 = 0.0f;
private float alpha3 = 0.0f;

private boolean falling;
private boolean start;
private boolean everyOther;
private boolean gameOver;
private boolean fadeIn=true;

//Input
private final KeyManager keyManager;
private final MouseInput mouseInput;

Plate[] plate = new Plate[1000];
Ball ball;

//Bilder
private BufferedImage briffaBackground1;
private BufferedImage briffaBackground2;

public Game(String title, int width, int height){
    this.falling = true;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.title = title;
    keyManager = new KeyManager();
    mouseInput = new MouseInput();        
}

private void init(){      
    display = new Display(title, width, height);
    display.getFrame().addKeyListener(keyManager);
    display.getFrame().addMouseListener(mouseInput);
    display.getFrame().addMouseMotionListener(mouseInput);
    briffaBackground1 = 
ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/briffaBackground1.png");
    briffaBackground2 = 
ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/briffaBackground2.png");
    //DrawPlate
    for(int f=0; f<plate.length; f++){
        plate[f] = new Plate((int) (Math.random() * 420),600-margin*f, 80, 
10);
    } 
    ball = new Ball(30, 30, 250, 300);
}

private void tick(){
    keyManager.tick();
    System.out.println(mouseInput.getX());
    if(keyManager.space){
        start=true;
    }

    if(start){
        if(keyManager.left&&ball.getxPos()>0){
            int x = ball.getxPos();
            x-=dxBall;
            ball.setxPos(x);
        }else if(keyManager.right&&ball.getxPos()<500-30){
            int x = ball.getxPos();
            x+=dxBall;
            ball.setxPos(x);
        }

        //Rörelse
        for (Plate plate1 : plate) {
            int newX = plate1.getyPos() + velY;
            plate1.setyPos(newX);
        }

        //Collision Detection
        if(falling){
            for(int i=wentBy; i<plate.length; i++){

if(ball.getBounds().intersects(plate[i].getBounds())&&velY<=0){
                    falling=false;
                }
            }
        }

        //Launch


        if(falling){
            everyOther=!everyOther;
            if(everyOther){
                velY-=dyPlate;
            }
        }else{
            velY=10;
            xMargin++;
            if(xMargin>20){
                falling=true;
                xMargin=0;
            }
        }
        if(plate[wentBy].getyPos()<0){
            gameOver=true;
        }
    }
 }

 private void render(){
    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    //ClearScreen
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //Draw
    switch(background){
        case 1:
            g.drawImage(briffaBackground1, 0, 0, null);
            break;
        case 2:
            g.drawImage(briffaBackground2, 0, 0, null);
            break;
    }
    if(wentBy>5){
        background=2;
    }

    if(!gameOver){
        for(int i=wentBy; i<10+wentBy; i++){
            if(plate[i].getyPos()>800){
                wentBy++;
            }
            plate[i].paint(g);
            ball.paint(g);
        }
    }else{
        gameOver(g);
        btnRestart(g);
        btnMainmenu(g);
    }

    //End Draw
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
public void gameOver(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
   AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha1));
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.
VALUE_ANTIAL
IAS_ON);
    if(alpha1<0.9f){
        alpha1+=0.02f;
    }
    if(gameOverY>200){
        gameOverY--;
    }
    g.setFont(header);
    g.drawString("GAME OVER", 100, gameOverY);
}

public void btnRestart(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
    AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha2));

g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints
.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    if(gameOverY==200){
        if(alpha2<0.999f){
            alpha2+=0.01;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(125, 250, 250, 70);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(button);
        g.drawString("Restart", 180, 298);
    }
}

public void btnMainmenu(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
    AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha3));

 g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints
 .VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    if(alpha2>0.15f){
        if(alpha3<0.999f){
            alpha3+=0.01;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(125, 370, 250, 70);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(button);
        g.drawString("Main Menu", 150, 418);
    }
}


@Override
public void run(){

    init();

    int fps=60;
    double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

    while(running){
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
        lastTime = now;

        if(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            render();
            delta--;
        }
    }

    stop();
}

public synchronized void start(){
    if(running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;
    running = false;

    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although i asked you to post your code, i may have found your problem. I've never worked with mouseMotionListener but it should be like this:

```
private class MyListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        currentRect = new Rectangle(x, y, 0, 0);
        updateDrawableRect(getWidth(), getHeight());
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        updateSize(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        updateSize(e);
    }

    void updateSize(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        currentRect.setSize(x - currentRect.x,
                            y - currentRect.y);
        updateDrawableRect(getWidth(), getHeight());
        Rectangle totalRepaint = rectToDraw.union(previouseRectDrawn); 
        repaint(totalRepaint.x, totalRepaint.y,
                totalRepaint.width, totalRepaint.height);
    }
}
```

Seems like mouseDragged() is a function while mousePressed() is invoked. so mousePress() stores the coordinates of the start of the drag, mouseDragged() updates the mouse's coordinates, and finally mouseRelease();

The full tutorial is found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html).

Comment: But It does not seem to work. I'll follow the tutorial instead. Thank you